# base32 image for img tag

Tags: java, encoding, base64, base32

I have faced an interesting thing as... if I use this code to download image as a string for Base64 encoded byte array it works fine

```
data:image/png;base64,<String>
```

But I was tring to encode the same image to Base32 and call it as

```
data:image/png;base32,<String>
```

But that way doesn't work. Maybe I am using some wrong protocol or something... :(

So my question is...
How to call Base32 image for img tag?

Thanks

Comment: how about a little more context: show some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the browser isn't displaying the image, all it means is that the browser doesn't support base32. I have the same issue with Iceweasel4, Firefox 3, and Chrome 12. IE7 doesn't show either base64 or base32-encoded inline images.

Here are the files I'm using for test, stolen from http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html:

test1.html shows fine in Firefox, Iceweasel, Chrome:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZf
YmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPbWLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcj
IQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVrApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZe
H9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KTkpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinON
s3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxMAF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon
4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=">
```

test2.html doesn't show in any browser I have.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base32,I5EUMOBZMFIAADYAUIAAACYLNL77776PB4H5LKVRRGAK
MZTGM3LF6YTHLKJSD6IEAQKAB7YAFQAAAAAAKAAA6AAAAPNVROW47YYMUSKXXA4OXTN375QKQBCD
JEIEO6QMQYY2Q2R3QR2G2BZDEEHQJYATAJA4656QTFXMQZDGOQABY5RIUAYLK2YCSTMFWLSFFDGU
QQPPRST6F6FOTBZ7VIQOAQCRQ6BGHCTWWRVMSZPB7XF36ZTGY2YBNBUII4IXOJZITDDODYRQM34S
SOJJC33GHYMW3B4CRF3I5CFAOCPRQ6D6PN6XW6JNQGOIPBVQUGFHHDNTO4CQCKCFC5RGDPBGMUNZ
XHEFQNXJ7F46OUOEYAC5PFOECUK6AZLFTVZCXDHQMCTHKJB44JJNA7MOKHLYYAYHSLZKE7RON4CL
XDY7JVYV674PT6QOBEADW===">
```

I used b64decode and b32encode from Python's base64 module to create the base32-encoded image from the base64-encoded image.

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397, the formats supported are base64 and plain ASCII (for those characters outside the range of printable 7-bit characters, you use the standard %XX hex-encoding.)

IE apparently doesn't support any in-line images until IE8.

Comment: well firefox 5.0 is showing base64 images but I need some format for more old browsers... Can you advise what image string format that should be then?

Comment: base64, if you want inline images, seems to be supported well. it even works on my old iPod touch under MobileSafari

Comment: That's right. I want to get string byte array image from server . Standart code like a Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you need then. you know how to encode to base64, and base64 works on all browsers I've tried except for IE.

Comment: But I am wondering is there a way to make a more supported format to make more old browsers get string image?

Comment: It' greate but what about the IE? Why it doesn't support it then? Actually, I heard IE should support base64 but I couldn't test it in practice... What IE version supports base64?

Comment: Oh, I got it :) IE is an exception then, right? Anyway thank you for your tests and interesting advising :)