# Confusions about different ways of displaying images from an external url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, base64, fetch-api

I recently learned there seem to be multiple ways to display an image on a web page.

The first way is to directly assign the URL to an image element's URL

```js
const img = new Image();

img.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector("#myImage").src = url;
};
img.onerror = () => {};

img.src = imageUrl;
```

Another way I recently learned is using `fetch`

```js
fetch(imageUrl)
    .then((response)=>response.blob())
    .then((blob)=>{
       const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
       document.querySelector("#myImage").src = objectUrl;
})
```

I have a few questions about both approaches:

1. I am familiar with `fetch` but I normally use it to fetch JSON. The second way of using `fetch` to get the image seems to me like we are fetching raw binary data of that image file over HTTP, while the first one we are delegating the browser to kick off a `Get` request to fetch that image. But from the server's perspective, there are no differences in terms of how it sends the image down? Am I understanding this right?
2. In what situations we should favor one approach over the other? I feel like the second approach is going to have a lot of CORS problems than the first one, but not sure exactly why.
3. Are there any other ways to display an image on a web page? I heard of base64 encoding/decoding a lot when people talk about images. Is base64 related to `response.blob()` i.e. the second approach? Or it is different? If so, can someone please give me an example of using base64 to show an image?
4. Lastly, I think displaying images has been a hole in my knowledge of frontend or web development. Please feel free to recommend any good resources on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Direct Answer

1. Yes the server can send any kind of data (anything is just a binary consecution of numbers, even text and characters). It is the client which tries to make sense of the content, usually following certain standards.
2. If you don't need to manipulate the image I suggest you to avoid any request since the browser can handle it for you. Note that only `fetch` is hardly subjected to CORS because it does not send cross-origin cookies (see [MDN - using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)). If you need more control you can use [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). The usage of blob is inherited from old web approaches, those times where `ArrayBuffer` were not invented, and it was the only wrapper for binary data in the web environments. It is still supported for many reason.
3. Actually less than you think (just 1)! Check explanation...
4. Image resources are widely dependent on what kind of processing you need... Just displaying an image? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) are full of tips, you just need to search for them. If you want to process an image instead, you need to take a further look to canvas elements and the usual resources are scarce or almost about game making (for obviously reasons), MDN and something in CSS-tricks for resources.

## Explanation

### What is an image?

I think you have a bias toward the concept of a browser displaying an image.

So what a image really is? **binary data.**

Pratically there is only one way for your browser (or your computer in general) to display an image, that is to have a byte array that is a flatten view of the pixels of your image. So at the end of the day you will **ALWAYS** need to feed your broswer with binary data that is interpretable as a raw image (usually a set of *rgb(a)* pixels).

Yes, there is only *"ONE"* way to display an image on a computer. But there are different ways we can represent that image.

### Encoding

At low level, different computers represent numbers in different ways, so the web standards decided to represent images in so called *RGB8* or *RGBA8* encoding (Red-Green-Blue(-Alpha)-NumBits, 8 bits = 1 Byte). This means that each pixel is represented by an array of 4 bytes (numbers), each varying from 0 to 255. This array is the only thing your browser see as image.

At the end your image is something like this:

```
// using color(x, y) to describe the image pixels
[ red(0, 0), green(0, 0), blue(0, 0), alpha(0, 0), red(1, 0), ... ] =
[ 124, 12, 123, 255, 122, ... ]
```

Now that you can see an image as a linear array of pixels, we can decide how to write it down on a piece of paper (our "code"). The browser (usually and historically) parse every packet sent on the web in an HTML file as plain text, so we must use characters to describe our image, the standard is to **ONLY** use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (character encoding, superset of ASCII). We can write it in JS as an array of numbers for example.

But take a look to the number 255. Each time you send that number on the newtork you are sending 3 characters: '2', '5', '5'. Web comunicates only with characters so... Is there a way to make a compact representation of that number in order to send less bytes as possible (saving those guys who have slow connection!)?

**Base64** is the most famous encoding used to describe that linear array in the most compact way, because it compress the 255 characters into just 1 or 2 characters (depending on the sequence). Instead of representing number in base of 10, we can take rid of some characters we usually use as letters to represent more digits. So `'11' become 'a', '12' => 'b', '13' => 'c', ..., '32' => 'a', ..., '63' => 'Z', '64' => '10', '65' => '11', ..., '128' => '20'`, and so on. Furthermore this algorithm exploit more low level representation to encode more digits in one single character (that's why u will see some '=' at the end sometimes).

Take a look on different representation of the same image:

```
// JavaScript Array
[ /* pixel 1 */ 124, 12, 123, 255, /* pixel 2 */ 122, 12, 56, 255 ] // 67 characters
// (30 without spaces and comments)

// Base64
fAx7w796DDjDvw== // 16 characters
// Base32
3sc3r7v3qc1o7vAb== // 18 characters (always >= Base64)
```

It's easy to see why they choose base64 as common algorithm (and this example counts just for 2 pixels).

*[(Base32 image example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554843/base32-image-for-img-tag)*

### Formats

Now imagine to send a 4K image on the web, which has a dimension of 3'656 × 2'664. This means that you are sending on the internet 9'739'584 of pixels, with 4 bytes each, for a grand total of 38'958'336 bytes (~39MB). Furthermore imagine what a waste if the image is completely black (we can describe the whole image just with one pixel)... That's too much (especially for low connections), for this reason they invented some algorithms which can describe the image in a more compact way, we call them **image format**. PNG and JPEG/JPG are example of formats which compress the image (jpg 4k image ~8MB, png 4k image can vary from ~2MB to ~22MB depending on certain parameters and the image itself).

Someone keep the compression thing to a further level, enstabilishing the `gzip` compression standard format (a generic compression algorithm over an already compressed image, or any other kind of file).

### Drawing on the Browser

At the end of this journey you have just two different ways browsers allow you to draw content: `URI` and `ArrayBuffer`.

- `URI`: you can use it with `<img>` and css, by setting `src` property of the element or by setting any style property which can get an image `URL` as input.
- `ArrayBuffer`: by manipulating the `<canvas>.context` buffer (that is just the linear array we discussed above)

Obviously browsers allow also to convert or switch between the two ways.

### URI

`URI` are the way we define a certain content, that can be a stored resource (`URL` - all protocols but `data`, for example `http(s)://`, `ws(s)://` or `file://`) or a properly buffer described by a string (the `data` protocol).

When you ask for an image, by setting the `src` property, your browser parses the URL and, if it is a remote content, makes a request to retrieve it and parse the content in the proper way (format & encoding). In the same way, when you make a `fetch` call you are asking the browser to request the remote content; the `fetch` function has the possibility to get the response in different ways:

- textual, just a bunch of characters (usually used to parse JSON/DOM/XML)
- binary data, divided in:

  - `ArrayBuffer`, which is a representation of the linear array of the image, we discussed above
  - `Blob`, which is an abstract representation of a generic file-like object (which also encapsulate an internal `ArrayBuffer`). The `Blob` is something like a pointer to a file-like entity in the browser cache, so you don't need to download/request the same file multiple times.

```js
// ArrayBuffer from fetch:
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
// Blob from fetch
fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
})
// ArrayBuffer from Blob
blob.arrayBuffer();
```

So now you have to tell to the browser how to make sense of the content you get back from the response. You need to convert the data to a parsable url:

```
var encodedURI = `data:${format};${encoding},` + encodeBuffer(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
image.src = encodedURI

// for base64 encoding
var encodeBuffer = function(buffer) { return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buffer)); } 

// for blobs
image.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
```

Note that browsers supports other encodings than just base64, also base32 is available but, as we saw above, is not so convinient to use. Also there is no builtin function like `btoa` to encode a buffer in base32.

Note also that the **format** value can be any kind of [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) such as `image/png|jpg|gif|svg` or `text/plain|html|xml`, `application/octet`, etc.. Obviously only image types are then shown as images.

When the resource is not requested from a remote server (with a `file://` or `data` protocol) the image is usually loaded syncronously, so as soon you set the URL, the browser will read, decode and put the buffer to display in your image. This has two consequences:

1. The data is managed locally (no internet connection requirements)
2. The data is treated synchronously, so if the image is big your computer will stuck into the processing until the end (see why it is a bad practice to use `data` protocol for videos or huge data in the special section, at the end)

##### URL vs URI

`URI` is a generic identifier for a resource, `URL` is an identifier for a location ***where*** to retrieve the resource. Usually in a browser context are almost an overlapped concept, I found this image explain better than thousand words:
[image: URL vs URI]

The `data` is pratically an `URI`, every request with a protocol is actually an `URL`

##### Side Note

In your question you write this as an alternative method by "setting the image element url":

```
fetch(imageUrl)
    .then((response)=>response.blob())
    .then((blob)=>{
       const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
       document.querySelector("#myImage").src = objectUrl; // <-- setting url!
})
```

But watch out: you actually setting an image element source URL!

### Canvas

The `<canvas>` element gives you the full control over an image buffer, also to further process it. You can literally draw your array in it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
// or offline canvas:
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = myWidth;
canvas.height = myHeight;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// exemple from array buffer
var arrayBuffer = /* from fetch or Blob.arrayBuffer() or also with new ArrayBuffer(size) */
var buffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(arrayBuffer);
var imageData = new ImageData(buffer, width, height);
context.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);

// example image from array (2 pixels)
var data = [
//   R    G    B    A
    255, 255, 255, 255, // white pixel
    255,   0,   0, 255  // red pixel
];
var buffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(data);
var imageData = new ImageData(buffer, 2, 1);
context.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);
```

*(Note ImageData wants a RGBA array)*

To get back the `ArrayBuffer` (which you can also plug back in the `image.src` after) you can do:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.heigth);
var buffer = imageData.data; // Uint8ClampedArray
var arrayBuffer = buffer.buffer; // ArrayBuffer
```

This is an example on how to process an image:

```
// reading image
var image = document.getElementById('myimage');
image.onload = function() {
    // load image in canvas
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
   
    // process your image
    context.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    imageData.data[0] = 255;

    // converting back to base64 url
    var resultUrl = window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, imageData.data.buffer));
   
    // setting image url and disabling onload
    image.onload = null;
    image.src = resultUrl;
};

// note src setted after onload
image.src = 'ANY-URL';
```

For this part I suggest you to take a look to [Canvas Tutorial - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

#### **SPECIAL**

Audio and Video are treated in the same way, but you must encode and format also the time and sound dimension in some way. You can load a [audio/video from base64](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/) string ([not so good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763939/13332423) for videos) or [display a video on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas)

Answer (score 6):

## To answer your questions

1. It's basically same from the server side, except for headers and information the browser could send along, whereas in fetch you have full control over headers
2. The fetch method could be used for more flexible or further parameters requiring requests or secure transfers you might implement in your server. For instance, requiring a post request that has header or body containing certain data to permit transfer of image... or for flexible transfers such as data that could be put in chunks that you could later assemble and manipulate before presenting.
3. Using base64 is almost the same as binary, though it is used to transfer images/data through mediums designed to transfer text. This is because base64 uses ascii number and letters to represent any data.

**Here, you can see an image generated from base64 string characters, without any link**

```html
<img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></img>
```

This is also helpful to embed image directly in code as text, pass it in as a url parameter or you can even put image in **JSON** file. In some cases, it also performs better than binary image with compression like gzip too.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation! I am still a little confused on the whole base64 thing. 
1. is the string you passed to `src` of the `img` tag called a base64 encoding? and it can be decoded by the browser to show the picture?
2. if we embedded that base64 encoding into the `src`, does that mean the image and the HTML are sent all together, as opposed to separate requests?

Comment: Yes, the string passed to the `src` is base64 string. The browser decodes and displays it. And it's loaded once with the html code and no further is made.

Answer (score 2):

strait to the point. basically you need to fetch the image instead of adding the url source at the html when you dont want people to see where yow pic is hosted at. if I right click on the image and you have the url directly in the img tag literally err body will be able to download the image, and not only that if I play around with the posible parameters that it might have I could not only get the image, but also get other images. so if you dont want to expose where yow pic is at you can "**hide**" it.

there are 4 ways you can get an image

- html
- css
- blob
- base64

but those 4 ways can be separated in two groups.

- handled by the browser

  - html
  - css
  - base64 ...*kindof*
- handled by you

  - blob
  - base64 ...*kindof*

the first group is not relevant as the browser will remove the image when it doesnt need it any mow show it when need it and more stuff.

why base64 could be included in that group ? bcuz if the image is not need it any more the browser cleans the memory used by it. so you just have to parse the binary into base64 and the browser will free any resource used by the pic, but on the other hand blobs are entirely managed and handled by you. so if you dont free the resources used by the pic the memory used in other words wont be able to be used by some other process/program/app, probably you're thinking why blob is prefered over base64?

> BLOB stands for Binary Large Object which could be anything - text, images, video, executable code, random bytes, etc. Most databases have a special BLOB type that allows storing this type of data.
>
> Base64 is an encoding that lets you represent any data as plain text. It can be easily be shown on the screen and useful in cases where binary data could be difficult to work with. For example, I could copy/paste the Base64 in the text field here but I won’t be able to do that with binary data. Also, Base64URL encoding is often used in HTTP URLs.

not only the source of yow pic is exposed, it also becomes over 30% bigger/heavier

```js
const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

fileElem.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
  if (!this.files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    const list = document.createElement("ul");
    fileList.appendChild(list);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);

      const image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[i]);
      image.onload = function() {
        image.setAttribute("src", this.result)
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.result);
      }
      li.appendChild(img);
      const info = document.createElement("span");
      li.appendChild(info);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none">
<button type="button" id="fileSelect">Select some files</button>
<div id="fileList">
  <p>No files selected!</p>
</div>
```

if you run the example and you right click on them images you'll see an url created, try to open it in another tab or so and you'll see the pic is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

1. The second way is called [Data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which allow embed small files inline in HTML/CSS, for example:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

this method can effectively reduce network requests during web page loading progress.

2. In the follwing situations, Data URL is applicable:

- embed **small** files in html to reduct reqeusts
- embed all assets in a single html for archive purpose
- load resource dynamically generated by server

3. The `base64` way is just Data URL, in addition to these two methods:

- SVG image can directly embed in HTML by `<svg>` tag
- Image can also be dynamically rendered using `<canvas>` API

4. Recommand a book to you `The definitive guide to HTML5`.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. can you expound on your first point - why is that the method can effectively reduce network requests during web page loading progress, compared to assigning the URL to `img.src`?

Comment: image binary is directly base64 encoded in `src` attribute in the `Data URI` way, so there is no need to rquest a URL like `http://yourdomain/logo.png`

Comment: is there any differences between Data URI and Data URL? You said base64 way is just Data URI. Is this different than the second method?

Comment: sorry, that's my spelling error...

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you want to show image on webpage than we have 2 ways for that

1. Set image web URL to img property
2. Set binary code to img property

Option 1 is used when you have stored image to your server folder as a file

Option 2 is used when you have stored image as binary base64 to your database so you retrieve as binary code only or else you have create image from your binary code and than set as per option 1